# Resizing a dnd panel in Java

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, awt

I an writing a DnD program to implement the dragging function. Everything works fine before I resize the frame. The JLabel was draggable inside the panel without any problem. But, when I try to resize my window, the JLabel pops back to its original position(fortunately, the DnD function is still workable). How can I prevent the JLabel to pop back to its original position? Is it something to do with the repaint function?(Maybe I have to override the function?) Here is my code for the JFrame constructor:

```
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    textField = new JTextField();
    getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    MainPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(MainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    MainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));


    Left_Panel = new JPanel();
    Left_Panel.setTransferHandler(new DragAndDropTransferHandler());
    Left_Panel.setDropTarget(new DropTarget(MainFrame.this, new MyDropTargetListener(this)));
    Left_Panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Panel 1"));
    MyLabel ML = new MyLabel();
    ML.setBounds(50 , 70, 61, 16);
    Left_Panel.add(ML);
    MainPanel.add(Left_Panel);

    Right_Panel = new JPanel();
    Right_Panel.setBounds(201, 0, 200, 400);
    Right_Panel.setTransferHandler(new DragAndDropTransferHandler());
    Right_Panel.setDropTarget(new DropTarget(MainFrame.this, new MyDropTargetListener(this)));
    Right_Panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Panel 2"));
    MainPanel.add(Right_Panel);

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

This is the drop function for my target listener.

```
    @Override
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
    DataFlavor dragAndDropPanelFlavor = null;
    Object transferableObj = null;
    Transferable transferable = null;

    try {
        dragAndDropPanelFlavor = MainFrame.getFlavor();
        transferable = dtde.getTransferable();
        dtde.getDropTargetContext();
        // What does the Transferable support
        if (transferable.isDataFlavorSupported(dragAndDropPanelFlavor)) {
            transferableObj = dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(dragAndDropPanelFlavor);
        } 

    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        System.out.println("Error");
    }

    if (transferableObj == null) return;
    if (transferableObj instanceof MyLabel) {
        MyLabel ML = (MyLabel) transferableObj;
        ML.setBounds(dtde.getLocation().x, dtde.getLocation().y, 61, 16);
    } 
}
```

I am only working on the Left panel for the time being. Tell me if I need to provide more code.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: Sounds like a possible layout issue to me, but to say for sure, I second @AndrewThompson's recommendation that you create and post a valid [mcve] with your question (not in a link).

Comment: Yes, your Left_Panel (which should be renamed leftPanel to conform to Java naming conventions) uses a default FlowLayout, and you appear to be adding components and setting their bounds via `setBounds(...)` and the two don't work well together. Consider giving your left JPanel a layout that works better with your current needs, perhaps a `null` layout if you're going to be manually moving components at runtime or even better, a custom layout manager.

Comment: `...or even better, a custom layout manager` For example you can check out the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/).

Comment: Thanks, for your advices. I took @HovercraftFullOfEels advice. I set the layout to null and it works fine now. (I didn't know the default layout is flow layout, I thought it was null). Btw, thanks for all your advice on nomenclature. I will put more effort on it after on. (P.S. I am a self-learner. I learnt programming all by myself T_T always feel helpless)